# I'm getting a PXLineNbrAttribute error after deploying customization

Tags: acumatica

I'm creating 2 customizations which work fine on my development machine but when they're deployed, I get the following error.  Both customizations show this, and they're not related in what they do.  Has anyone else run into this?

[image: Acumatica Error]
Thanks,

Peter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We added an optional parameter on PXLineNbrAttribute in the version 5.20.1983 that unfortunately broke the binary compatibility. My guess is that you developed your customization in a version prior to 5.20.1983 and that your deployment environment is in a version higher or equal to 5.20.1983.

The solution would be to update your development environment to the same version of your production environment and recompile the project.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought it might be a version issue - but even purely on my development site, when I search for PXLineNbrAttribute and find it - it has a warning line underneath, saying:


"The type 'PX.Data.PXLineNbrAttribute' in C:\Program Filesl (x86)\Acumatica ERP\AcumaticaERP\App_Data\CodeRepository\PX.Data\Maintenance\Attribute.cs conflicts wiht the importe type PX.Data.PXLineNbrAttribute in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Acumatica\AcumaticaERP\Bin\PX.Data.dll."

Just wondering why a file on the website would have a different reference than the dll that's in the Bin folder...

thx...

Comment: The code in the folder CodeRepository is for reference only. We put it there so that you can easily refer to it when building your projects. The real code which is executed is compiled in the dll PX.Data.dll located in the bin folder. The warning you got is only because visual studio see the files in code repository as actual code (even if its never compiled or executed). You can ignore that.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks again - your help is much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome! Please flag as answered if that fixed your problem.